# how to change vote into voted after user votes the choices?

Tags: python, django

This Code is working perfectly. The only thing I want to change is submit button "Vote" into "Voted" after user voted the option ,instead of displaying error message " You Already Voted".So that the user can know which options he voted already when he logs in to vote the option next time

> urls.py

```
   path('<slug>/',views.options,name='options'),
   path('<slug>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
```

> models.py

```
 class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
    details = models.TextField(blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True,upload_to='categories')
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"


class Option(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True,upload_to='options')
    details = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=CASCADE)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Vote(models.Model):
    option = models.ForeignKey(Option, on_delete=CASCADE)
    voter = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='option')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.voter
```

> views.py

```
def options(request,slug):
category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
category.views += 1
category.save()
options = category.option_set.all().order_by('-votes')
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.category = category
            comment.user = request.user
            comment.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Comment Posted.')
    else:
        messages.error(request, 'You have to login first to give comment')
        return redirect('rank:login')
else:
    form = CommentForm()
return render(request, 'rank/options.html', {'options': options,'form':form,'title': 'options','category':category})

def vote(request,slug):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    option = Option.objects.get(slug=slug)
    category = option.category

    if Vote.objects.filter(slug=slug,voter_id=request.user.id).exists():
         messages.error(request,'You Already Voted!')
         return redirect('rank:options', category.slug)
    else:
        option.votes += 1
        option.save()
        voter = Vote(voter=request.user,option=option)
        voter.save()
        messages.success(request,'Voted.{} peoples also agree with you.'.format(option.votes-1))
        return redirect('rank:options',category.slug)
else:
    messages.error(request,"You have to login first to vote.")
    return redirect('rank:login')
```

> options.html

```
<ol type="1">
          <center>{% bootstrap_messages %}</center>
    {% for option in options %}

     <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 mb-6">
              <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <b><li>
                  <img src="/media/{{option.image}}" width="400" height="300">
                 <h4>{{option.name}}
                  </h4>
                  <h5 class="card-text">{{ option.details}}</h5>
                      <h5>{{ option.votes }} votes</h5>
                       <form action="{% url 'rank:vote' option.slug %}" method="post">
                           {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Vote" >
                       </form>
                         </li></b>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                  <small class="text-muted"></small>
                </div>


              </div>
                </div>
         {% empty %}
    <div class="card w-100">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h4>Item not available</h4>
    </div>
    </div>

    {% endfor %}
     </ol>
```

Comment: where is your options view?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this might be to add an attribute to each option to indicate whether the currently logged in user has voted on that option before you pass the options to the template.

For example:

```py
def options(request,slug):
    category = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
    category.views += 1
    category.save()
    options = category.option_set.all().order_by('-votes')

    # Indicate whether the user has voted or not
    for option in options:
        option.has_voted = option.vote_set.filter(voter=request.user).exists()

    ...

    return render(request, 'rank/options.html', {'options': options,'form':form,'title': 'options','category':category})
```

And then you can check the `has_voted` attribute in the template when you render the button:

```
{% if option.has_voted %}
    You already voted
{% else %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Vote" >
{% endif %}
```

Comment: @peter - did this answer your question?